# What does "maximum geometric error of a chunk" mean?

Tags: computational-geometry

In [this](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/sig-notes.pdf) paper, on the top of page 7 it says,

> Where $\delta$ is the **maximum geometric error of a chunk** ...

What does that mean? Thanks :D

Comment: It's mentioned even earlier, on page 6: "Each chunk has a bounding volume associated with it, as well as a maximum geometric error, $\delta$. $\delta$ represents the maximum geometric deviation of a chunk (in object space) from the portion of the underlying full-detail mesh it represents." Is that sufficient for you?

Comment: Why should there be any _deviation_?

Comment: Because the coarser meshes don't have the level of detail of the full-detail mesh. Think of trying to approximate a smooth curve with four line segments, or more relevantly here, approximating that five-line approximation with just two line segments.